# How to encode a sentence using an attention mechanism?

Tags: nlp, encoding, attention-mechanism

Recently, I read about one of the state-of-the-art method called Attention models. This method use a Encoder-Decoder model. It can find a better encoding for each word in a sentence. But how can I encode a full sentence?

For example, I have a sentence "I love reading".

After embedding, this sentence will be converted to list of three vectors. (or matrix with dimension `number of words` times `embedding dimension`).

After several layers of attention mechanism, I will still have the same matrix.

How can I convert this matrix to a single vector that contains an encoded representation of the full sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard way of obtaining a sentence representation with attention models is using [BERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) or any other of its derivations, like [RoBERTa](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11692.pdf). In these models, the sentence tokens passed as input to the model are prefixed with a special token `[CLS]`. The output of the model at that first position is the sentence representation.

To use these models, you may use [sentence-transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) library, e.g.:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1')

sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.', 
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']

sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

for sentence, embedding in zip(sentences, sentence_embeddings):
    print("Sentence:", sentence)
    print("Embedding:", embedding)
    print("")
```

Comment: Is is possible to get the same from reformer model?

Comment: It is technically possible, but you need to find a reformer pretrained on a masked LM task. I am not aware of the existence of such a publicly available pretrained model.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert this matrix to a single vector that contains an encoded representation of the full sentence?

It's achieved by applying a softmax function to the attention scores and using these probabilities to derive a weighted sum of the encoder hidden states.

More specifically: In *Seq2Seq*, for example, with $N$ words let $h_1,...,h_N \in R^h$ be the encoder hidden states, $s_t \in R^h$ the decoder hidden states at timestep $t$, then the attention scores are $$e^t = [s_t^Th_1,...,s_t^Th_N] \in R^N.$$ Applying a softmax function gives the attention distribution $$\alpha^t = softmax(e^t) \in R^N.$$ And, finally, using these as weights in a weighted sum results in the attention output
$$a_t = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i^t h_i \in R^h.$$

By doing so, you reduce the sequence of $N$ words to a single vector of dimension $h$. This is also well explained in Stanford's [CS224N: Natural Language Processing with Deep Learning - Lecture 8](https://youtu.be/XXtpJxZBa2c) (around 1h 2mins).

Comment: This list of vectors already is a result of QKV-attention. The question was about how to get a single encoding for a full sentence, not encoding for each word.

Comment: @KenenbekArzymatov Not sure what you mean. $\alpha_t$ encodes the whole input sentence, not each word. Moreover, what I described is the attention mechanism. The input vectors $s_t$ and $h_n$ are the inputs to and not the result of attention (except for this being repeated over time steps, of course).